# Is it possible to get float type result from the sum of two integer type variable?

Tags: php, types, casting

Is it possible to get float type result from the sum of two integer type variable?

Example:

```
1 + 2 => 3.0
```

I have tried using `number_format($result, 1)` and `sprintf("%.1f", $result)`,
but the return value type is string.

Additionally, if I type cast to float then the return value is a float of value `3` and not `3.0`

Comment: PHP uses type casting anyway, so the type doesn't matter _that_ much. Can you not just do `$result = (float)(1 + 2)`

Comment: yeah, i get double type value 3. but is it possible 3.00?

Comment: I don't understand, what difference does it make? If the value is `3` or `3.0` it makes no difference. If you are displaying the value then use the `number_format` as you have done, and then it, again, doesn't matter what the type is.

Comment: @RamKesavan I think what OP wants is to combine the formatting of number_format, but **retain the float type**.

Comment: @JustCarty thanks. You understand my query

Comment: However, I am afraid that that is not possible. I have tried everything but nothing seems to let you achieve that...

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you.. you can use sprintf:-

```
$a = 1+2;
$result = sprintf("%.2f", $a); //3.00  or  $result = sprintf("%.1f", $a); //3.0
echo $result;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

use `floatval();` to swith the value to float

[check the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

also please check the similar question [PHP - Force integer conversion to float with three decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907129/php-force-integer-conversion-to-float-with-three-decimals)

Answer (score 0):

Your integer variables are in the type `int`

If you **add** two `int` type, the result is inevitably an integer result.

```
$intOne = 1;
$intTwo = 2;

$result = $intOne + $intTwo; // = (int)3
```

You can change the type of your result, easily, but, is not necessary good, if you store an int in your var...

```
$floatResult = (float) $result; // (float)3
```

Also, if you don't know the type of your variable you can use the function 'floatval' (official doc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)) like that:

```
$floatOne = floatval('3.14'); // (float)3.14
$floatTwo = floatval("3.141 is a Pi number"); // (float)3.14
```

In this case, if you add two flaot type, the result is in float two:

```
$result = $floatOne + floatTwo; // (float)6.281
```

The best practises want to save **the right type** on your variable and your database ( read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199388/why-are-there-so-many-numeric-types-bit-int-float-double-long) for more information about types and performance)

if you want just show decimals after your integer type, you can use the `number_format()` function (official documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)) like that:

```
$decimalResult = number_format($floatResult, 4);
echo $decimalResult; // Show '3.0000'        ^ Number of decimals
```

Hope I help you ;)